# Display image on browser, where image get from the API response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on sample application, where I have to show generated QR code. I am using http://goqr.me/api/ for generating the API.

Here is my sample code

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def submit_qr
    code = params[:code]
    url = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=#{params[:code]}&size=220x220&margin=0"
    @response = HTTParty.get(url).parsed_response
  end
end
```

When I check the call from rails console I am getting following

```
irb(main):004:0> url = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=test&size=220x220&margin=0"
=> "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=test&size=220x220&margin=0"
irb(main):005:0> response = HTTParty.get(url)
=> #<HTTParty::Response:0x8efada0 parsed_response="\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\xDC\x00\x00\x00\xDC\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00!\x94]\xC2\x00\x00\x00\x06PLTE\xFF\xFF\xFF\x00\x00\x00U\xC2\xD3~\x00\x00\x01\x02IDATX\x85\xED\xD7\xBB\x11\x840\f\x04\xD0e\b\b)\xC1\xA5P\x1A\x94\xE6R(\x81\x90\x80A\x87\xFC\x05\x06\xCE\xC7\xA5\xAC\"\x8F\x1F\xD1\x0E\xB2lH\xAC\x01\xB5\x00\x8D\xA0\x8B;\x13\x88\x8A\x16Z\xB5\ff\x01\xCC\ft\xB3\xDBAO\f\xD8jRu\x88\x0F\x8A\xD5\xB6\xB3\x12\x9Fa\xCE\x96x\x13\x1F\\\xB3\x12\x9Faj\xDEmk\xD4\xE3\xED\xB2\xB3_\x8Ci\x00l\x7F\x9F\xC7\xDD\x00 \x16\xF0P\xBA\x85\xBBz+\x86\xA4j\xF1\xD0\x88\xD8fE7U\xDA\xB0\xC4\"Z\xE8i\xB6\xA0\x1F\xE1\xFF>(\xA6\xE3\x8D\xB8U\x15\xE6\xA7\x068\xC7\xAF\xC5M\x04b\tS\x8C&6n\xA3\xB4\xBA%1\xA1\xBF\xC2\xE6\xF8|\x7F\x12\x8B\x98\xCAH(\xBD~\xB8[\e\xF1t\xC3\x90\xF8\b?M\a\xE2\x17\xB4.\xD8\xF0\xC44!\xDB\xCE7/\xD1\xE1\xEE\x89\x99\xE7g\x8C\x8F\xF8\x17~\xCD\xF6\xCD\x18\a\x80m\x89?bl^\x97\xAD\xAE\xF5\x15@\xCC\x98\a\xC0!>9M\a\xE2\x15~\x00\xA9\xB7\xB6\x8EW\xEAb\xBE\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xAEB`\x82", @response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @headers={"date"=>["Fri, 20 Mar 2020 10:33:39 GMT"], "server"=>["Apache/2"], "access-control-allow-origin"=>["*"], "access-control-allow-methods"=>["POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"], "access-control-max-age"=>["7200"], "access-control-allow-headers"=>["Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Client-Security-Token"], "x-powered-by"=>["PHP/5.4.16"], "content-length"=>["333"], "connection"=>["close"], "content-type"=>["image/png"]}>
```

So how can I show the image on browser.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
response = "\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\xDC\x00\x00\x00\xDC\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00!\x94]\xC2\x00\x00\x00\x06PLTE\xFF\xFF\xFF\x00\x00\x00U\xC2\xD3~\x00\x00\x01\x02IDATX\x85\xED\xD7\xBB\x11\x840\f\x04\xD0e\b\b)\xC1\xA5P\x1A\x94\xE6R(\x81\x90\x80A\x87\xFC\x05\x06\xCE\xC7\xA5\xAC\"\x8F\x1F\xD1\x0E\xB2lH\xAC\x01\xB5\x00\x8D\xA0\x8B;\x13\x88\x8A\x16Z\xB5\ff\x01\xCC\ft\xB3\xDBAO\f\xD8jRu\x88\x0F\x8A\xD5\xB6\xB3\x12\x9Fa\xCE\x96x\x13\x1F\\\xB3\x12\x9Faj\xDEmk\xD4\xE3\xED\xB2\xB3_\x8Ci\x00l\x7F\x9F\xC7\xDD\x00 \x16\xF0P\xBA\x85\xBBz+\x86\xA4j\xF1\xD0\x88\xD8fE7U\xDA\xB0\xC4\"Z\xE8i\xB6\xA0\x1F\xE1\xFF>(\xA6\xE3\x8D\xB8U\x15\xE6\xA7\x068\xC7\xAF\xC5M\x04b\tS\x8C&6n\xA3\xB4\xBA%1\xA1\xBF\xC2\xE6\xF8|\x7F\x12\x8B\x98\xCAH(\xBD~\xB8[\e\xF1t\xC3\x90\xF8\b?M\a\xE2\x17\xB4.\xD8\xF0\xC44!\xDB\xCE7/\xD1\xE1\xEE\x89\x99\xE7g\x8C\x8F\xF8\x17~\xCD\xF6\xCD\x18\a\x80m\x89?bl^\x97\xAD\xAE\xF5\x15@\xCC\x98\a\xC0!>9M\a\xE2\x15~\x00\xA9\xB7\xB6\x8EW\xEAb\xBE\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xAEB`\x82"
decoded_image = Base64.strict_encode64(response)
base64_img = "data:image/png;base64," + decoded_image
```

Something like this